# What file system path is used by Android's Context.openFileOutput()?

Tags: android

I can't understand why the answer to this isn't in the Android developer docs; I find them consistently frustrating.

Re the openFileOutput() method on the Context class to open a file for writing, what internal storage file path does it write to?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Comment: `data > data > your app id > files`

Comment: phone needs to be rooted to view `/data/data`

Answer (score 69, accepted):

> Re the openFileOutput() method on the Context class to open a file for writing, what internal storage file path does it write to?

It points to where `getFilesDir()` on `Context` returns. You can tell this because the documentation says:

> Returns the absolute path to the directory on the filesystem where files created with openFileOutput(String, int) are stored.

Comment: I wish the docs were clear that the location can move around and what method to use to find the location (e.g. adding getFilesDir() to the See Also section). Many thanks Mark, appreciate your help.

Comment: @Ollie C: Yeah, it's strange that cross-reference isn't there. And one of the downsides of having the inherited stuff on every page (e.g., `openFileOutput()` in every `Context` subclass Javadoc) is that searching becomes somewhat more painful.

Comment: @CommonsWare, I am a newbie and this may seem a naive question but it is related to this topic:  When I am trying to save the file to my external storage using  context.openFileOutput(this.fileName, Context.MODE_APPEND) the method does not throw any exception and executes normally and Context.getFilesDir() returns: /data/data/com.proj.myproject/files.  but when I check my phone's external memory and go to /Data it is empty. I have added WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in manifest as well. Where could it be saving the file then ? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @powernit: `openFileOutput()` is [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html). Your phone's "external memory" is either [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) or perhaps [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html). None of those are the same thing.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Thank you, so if I am storing anything using openFileOutput() then only the application can read and write to it and it is private to that application. So only application in context can see it. This insight really helped me.

Answer (score 20):

In DDMS, I found my file under:

```
data > data > your app id > files
```

Comment: my data folder always looks empty, any idea what I may be missing?

Comment: it could be that your phone has multiple storages, now many phones have a few GB of internal storage that's called "sd0"(depends on your manufacture, some might choose another name), while also allow you to insert external storage like SD card which will be called "sd1", you will have to choose the right storage before look up for your app data.

Comment: Your phone needs to be rooted. Orelse the data folder will show empty.

Answer (score 3):

You can retrieve that file path by calling `Context#getFileStreamPath(String)`:

> Returns the absolute path on the filesystem where a file created with `openFileOutput(String, int)` is stored.

It returns a `File`, so then call `File#getAbsolutePath()`.

So summing up:

```
context.getFileStreamPath(name).getAbsolutePath()
```

Answer (score 2):

This file is written to a path relative to your app within the devices memory.
You may perhaps with `ddms` peek at the location, but when you are using this Context.openFileOutput(), you should not care about any absolute path.

If you want to pass the file name around you should consider using [external storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal).