# Where does a file get saved when openFileOutput is used?

Tags: android, file, android-sdcard

Is it possible to know where a file which is created by

```
ApplicationContext.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
```

get stored? I dont need any java code to print me the path, that should be `getFileStreamPath(filename)`, i just need the default storage location for such files. i didnt find any helpful things in the javadoc of android

Comment: You have accepted the wrong answer : see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4926027/what-file-system-path-is-used-by-androids-context-openfileoutput. You must accept the answer by @JosephusVillarey. Please do - that's only confusing

Comment: `data > data > your app id > files` ex: /data/data/com.example/files/--myfile.dat--

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this page : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html
You can get some path to directory.

I think, if you try to use directly `ApplicationContext.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);`, the file will be create at the root of the phone, but I'm not sure, or in the /data.

Comment: Confusing answer - see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4926027/what-file-system-path-is-used-by-androids-context-openfileoutput

Answer (score 3):

If you have a rooted phone, have a look at /data/data.
There will be a folder with your package name with all your files you've saved.

But you will need root an a root explorer to watch these files.

Answer (score 1):

If you call `getFilesDir()` and iterate through it, you can compare the filename string you used with `openFileOutput` to create the exact path for that file.

Answer (score 1):

Better follow Guillaume's answer and check Environment for what is the *current* location. Because openFileOutput is part of the Context class it changes based on the base context currently used. For example, during testing you can be given a [RenamingDelegatingContext](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/RenamingDelegatingContext.html) which overrides openFileOutput by renaming the files and can place them anywhere desired.