# Emailing a text file in background when button is clicked

Tags: java, android, android-intent, email

I want to attach a text file and email it automatically in background to a predefined email address when button is pressed.

I am creating a text file like this:

```
   try {
    FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("abc.txt",MODE_PRIVATE);
    String s = "Data to be written ok fine cool";fos.write(s.getBytes());
   } catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();

}
```

How will I setup the sending of email automatically?

Answer (score 2):

See [this link](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_%28no_Intents%29_in_Android) on how to send e-mails without an intent. As mentioned in the tutorial, you will need the [javamail-android libraries](http://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/downloads/list).

Note the `addAttachment` method in the `Mail` class.

Comment: Those methods are missing from the code sample for some reason. This was true when I used the code as well. Simply add the methods to the class and all they will need to do is set the class variable that is mentioned in the name of the method. `setFrom(String)` would set the `_form` variable, etc..

Comment: I want to attach the "abc.txt" file I created above in the mail, but don't know what filelocation will I give

Comment: You are using `openFileOutput`. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4926027/what-file-system-path-is-used-by-androids-context-openfileoutput

Comment: Don't know what I am doing wrong, no errors and nothing but email is not getting send http://smrtm.in/rCK1

Answer (score 0):

You could spawn a new thread that does the email sending for you...
Or perhaps a more elegant solution would be to spawn a second thread at the start of your application, and your main thread notifies the second thread when there is a new message to send.

Answer (score 0):

That's depend on how would u like to send email.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a) link show how to send email WITHOUT using default mail client.
And this to let user choose

```
private void sendEmail() {
        final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, String[]{"recipient@example.com"} );
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "content");
        this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To send the mail in background you can use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and to make it automatic(without using any Intent) [use JavaMail api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a/2033124#2033124).