# Why can't find Context.openFileOutput() path?

Tags: android, file

I'm trying to use this method to cache bitmaps. Don't get an error. But I can't find the files in the filesystem. Need to find them because the cache is not working properly and want to investigate.

I tried `Context.getFilesDir()` like described here [What file system path is used by Android's Context.openFileOutput()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4926027/what-file-system-path-is-used-by-androids-context-openfileoutput). It returns a path `/data/data/com.foo.bar/files` but I can't find this path on the device. Looking with a normal file explorer, searched for "foo", no results.

Also, how do I find it?

Comment: Oh, ok, thanks. Seems I was ignoring very basic knowledge.

Comment: It happens buddy.. Happy Coding..!