# Where the "myfilename.txt" in android phone being stored?

Tags: android, text-files

I compiled [this project](http://android-helper4u.blogspot.com/2013/02/9how-to-write-and-read-from-text-file.html) in Eclipse.

It is an android app.

I run it in my samsung mobile.  But I'm still wondering **where** the "myfilename.txt" is stored in the android phone.

I explore the internal storage of my phone by using DiskUsage(https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage&hl=en) app. I found that the data of the project exist in my phone but I can't preview it. Is there any apps that can view the internal storage? Thanks

Comment: And why don't you just consult the reference page for `openFileOutput()`?

Comment: possible dupplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4926027/what-file-system-path-is-used-by-androids-context-openfileoutput

Answer (score 0):

file will get stored on internal storage path is `data/data/package_name/files/`

Comment: Regardless of whether this is correct or not -- on should not rely on this.

Comment: The developer of this project said I can't access the text file on my device. So it doesnt matter where is the path because the file will never be accessed.

Comment: @doraemon: it can be access in emulator.try to run the app on emulator and pull the file using DDMS perpespective file explorer.u cant access within android device but u can see in emulator