# How to write an array to a text file on internal storage?

Tags: android, file, text, store, outputstream

I need to store some data as a text file on the internal storage.
for example below, I have a button, I'd like to save some data in a text file each time the button is clicked. I am testing an example in:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    Button b;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String filename = "myfile";
        String string = "Hello world!";
        FileOutputStream outputStream;

        try {
          outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_APPEND);
          outputStream.write(string.getBytes());
          outputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I only changed the "mode_private" to "mode_append", so I can see the saved file, but I cannot find the saved file, I even cannot find the directory in which the file is supposed to be saved.

Also, more specifically, I need to store an array of numbers in the text file (say i={1,2,3} to output.txt).
I would be grateful if you can help me out.

Comment: Regarding where the file is saved, see [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4926027/535871).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you are missing the `setOnClickListener` for your button. It should be...

```
b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
b.setOnClickListener(this);
```

*"but I cannot find the saved file, I even cannot find the directory in which the file is supposed to be saved."*

`getApplicationContext().getFilesDir()` will tell you where the file was saved.

Android DOCS say...

> Your app's internal storage directory is specified by your app's package name in a special location of the Android file system.

To store an array in a file, try the following...

```
String filename = "myfile";
String[] numbers = new String[] {"1, 2, 3"};
FileOutputStream outputStream;

try {
  outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_APPEND);
  for (String s : numbers) {  
      outputStream.write(s.getBytes());  
  } 
  outputStream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I found the directory using getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(), but it seems that this path is not created, so when I go through folders to actually see the saved file, I cannot find it, any idea? and about your code, I should be able to find a file named "myfile" under the directory in which the application is saved, is that correct?

Comment: No, as far as I know, you wont be able to see the file under the directory. `openFileOutput` will store the file in the app's internal storage directory. The only way to access the file is using the `Context`. If you want to access the actual file then store the file externally.

Comment: I just tested the same code, but this time using the emulator, and I am able to see the actual file and pull it from the device. It seems that I cannot see it when using the actual device instead of the emulator. Yeah, thanks anyway, I'll try to see if I can store the file externally, and I'll ask you again if I ran into a problem.