# Android, saving images in the 'App Container'

Tags: android

I wasn't sure how to word this, but in iOS terms, if I download an image, and save it in the documents directory, it saves it in the Apps Container, which is not visible to other apps, and camera roll etc.

The way I have it in Android currently, all of these images are visible in the File Explorer and Gallery.

I was wondering how I could save these images in a similar way to iOS and have them hidden in the Apps own container.

Is there a way to create a folder, with context.MODE_PRIVATE or something similiar?

This is what I have currently, does it do the trick?

```
public static Boolean saveToInternalStorage(Context context, Bitmap bitmap, String filename) {
        ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(context);

        //Path to /data/data/yourapp/app_data/imageDir
        File directory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        //Create imageDir
        File mypath = new File(directory, filename);

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);

            //Use the compress method on the BitMap object to write image to the OutputStream
            if (bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos)) {
                return true;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (fos != null) {
                    fos.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public static Bitmap loadImageFromStorage(Context context, String filename) {
        ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(context);

        //Path to /data/data/yourapp/app_data/imageDir
        File directory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        try {
            File f = new File(directory, filename);
            Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f));


            return b;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: I think [`getFilesDir()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir()) should work like this in `MODE_PRIVATE`. It takes the path `data/data/com.package.name/files/` and unless the device is rooted, this is impossible to see the saved file. See [Using internal storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) documentation. I answered [on related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34751705/2668136) which can give you more infos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I was wondering how I could save these images in a similar way to iOS and have them hidden in the Apps own container.

Write them to `getFilesDir()`, `getCacheDir()`, or another location on [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html).

> This is what I have currently, does it do the trick?

The `ContextWrapper` is useless. If you are downloading an image, I do not know why you have a `Bitmap` that you are trying to write to storage — download straight to storage.

But, with respect to keeping the images private to your app, `getDir()` also points to locations in internal storage.

Comment: How can I save the images directly to storage?

Comment: @BobbyW: Um, download them, presumably using an HTTP client API (`HttpUrlConnection`, OkHttp, etc.).

Answer (score 4):

Read this [article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal). This will help..

> You can save files directly on the device's internal storage. By default, files saved to the internal storage are private to your application and other applications cannot access them (nor can the user). When the user uninstalls your application, these files are removed.