# Android Studio read/write from .txt file, save path?

Tags: android

so im trying to write data that I recieve from a socket into text file and then read those data.

I have these 2 methods in my MainActivity (just tests to see how read and write from/into a file works) :

```
public void WriteBtn() {


    // add-write text into file
    try {
        FileOutputStream fileout=openFileOutput("mytextfile.txt", MODE_PRIVATE);
        OutputStreamWriter outputWriter=new OutputStreamWriter(fileout);
        outputWriter.write("Test");
        outputWriter.close();

        //display file saved message
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "File saved successfully!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public void ReadBtn() {
    //reading text from file
    try {
        FileInputStream fileIn=openFileInput("mytextfile.txt");
        InputStreamReader InputRead= new InputStreamReader(fileIn);

        char[] inputBuffer= new char[256];
        String s="";
        int charRead;

        while ((charRead=InputRead.read(inputBuffer))>0) {
            // char to string conversion
            String readstring=String.copyValueOf(inputBuffer,0,charRead);
            s +=readstring;
        }
        InputRead.close();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), s,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I call them with buttons but I was wondering, where does it save my "mytextfile.txt" ???

Comment: I am pretty sure it is context dependent, saving to its current set file directory. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4926027/what-file-system-path-is-used-by-androids-context-openfileoutput

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Context.getExternalFilesDir() and pass it Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS.  That should give you the default output path for text files.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)

**EDIT**
I just tested this.  It looks like Context.openFileOutput() dumps everything, regardless of file type, to Conext.getFilesDir()
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir()

Comment: i managed to retrieve the path using getFilesDir() /data/user/0/sevrain.test/files 
is there anyway to access it in explorer ?

Comment: @Sech, The application's files directory is internal to the application and private, so file explorers will not be able to browse _unless_ the phone is rooted (or you're using an emulator). You could embed your own sort of file browser in your app (try getFilesDir().listFiles() to grab a list of internal files).  Alternatively, if you're not trying to protect the file, you could just write out to shared memory - don't use getFilesDir() but just use a path to the public storage like new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/mytestfile.txt");